# How do I forecast with external regressors in the rugarch package in R? The regressor appears to always be ignored in the forecasting

Tags: r, garch

Here's the code to fit a GARCH(1,1) model with a external regressor x.

```
library(rugarch)
set.seed(1)
x <- matrix(rnorm(1000))
y <- rnorm(1000,mean=x)*x + rnorm(1000)
garchspec <- ugarchspec(mean.model=list(external.regressors=y),
                        variance.model=list(model="sGARCH", garchOrder=c(1,1)))
fit <- ugarchfit(spec=garchspec, data=y)
```

Now here's what I did to try to forecast:

```
newdata <- matrix(rnorm(10))
ugarchforecast(fit, external.forecasts=list(newdata))
```

The problem is, it seems the `external.forecasts` does nothing. You can delete it and get the same forecast, you can even put nonsense that should throw up an error, but it still outputs the same forecasts:

```
ugarchforecast(fit)

ugarchforecast(fit, external.forecasts=list(factor(NaN)))
```

I have looked in the documentation, and searched the internet, and cannot find any one showing code with this working.

How can I forecast the model with the regressor values `newdata`?

Comment: This question is off-topic here. The documentation could be clearer but `external.forecasts` must be a named list, and the future values of exogenous regressors in the mean equation must be in the `mregfor` element of the list (the ones in the variance equation go in the `vregfor` element). So, like this: `ugarchforecast(fit, external.forecasts=list(mregfor=newdata))`. If the list does not contain an `mregfor` element, it is assumed to be zero.